# How do I download a file with a non-HTML content type from within a browser?

Tags: browser, download, mime-types, content-negotiation

I'm trying to use content negotiation to give both a HTML and a RDF/XML representation of a resource on a HTTP server. On the server side this works, i.e.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" http://localhost:8182/ontologies/1
```

will retrieve the correct version. I can also do the same with JavaScript/Dojo:

```
function downloadOntologyRDF(ontologyId) {
    dojo.xhrGet( {
        url:"${baseUrl}/ontologies/" + ontologyId,
        headers: {"Accept": "application/rdf+xml"},
        timeout: 5000,
        load: function(response, ioArgs) {
            var preNode = document.createElement("pre");
            preNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response));
            var foo = new dijit.Dialog({
                title: "RDF",
                content: preNode,
                style: "overflow: auto;"
            });
            foo.show();
            return response;
        },
        error: function(response, ioArgs) {
            alert("Retrieving the RDF version failed: " + response);
            return response;
        }
    });
}
```

which will display the result in a popup dialog. The point where I am stuck is offering a way to the user to download this version. I would like to have a link on the page that either displays the RDF as a page in the browser or directly opens the save dialog. Is this possible at all without resorting to query parameters or other tricks?

Comment: I suspect that there isn't a way aside from server-side stuff like query parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like cobbal mentions - since you can not set Accept header in the URL itself, you should have additional content negotiation mechanism. Some frameworks allow content type to be set in form

```
http://example.com/resource;format
```

Having the `format` at the end of URL, separated with semicolon. Then, when processing request, it parses out the format part.

In your case it could be something like

```
http://localhost:8182/ontologies/1;rdf
```

to server rdf, and no format specified to serve whatever is in your accept headers.

Comment: That classifies as "query parameters and other tricks" for me ;-) But let me just accept this answer as a long version of "no".

Comment: at the time of writing i thought that semicolon is a good idea but it brings more trouble and not much of elegance in the business - you have to parse it or configure in the routing table and it gets nasty fast. for me at the end i went with a parameter localhost:8182/ontologies/1?format=rdf

Answer (score 0):

This page explains how to setup an aspx page that will show the RDF in the browser.  It may help you.  Although I can't be sure because you haven's specified what you are running on your server.

[Building an RSS feed made simple](http://www.uberasp.net/getarticle.aspx?id=17)

Comment: I'm using Java/Restlets, but it doesn't matter: the server side already does its thing as the curl/JS examples show. RSS feeds are considered separate resources with their own URL, what I try to do is to use content negotiation to retrieve a different variant of the same resource.